# Error when drawing a legend on a separate plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

I want to plot a legend on a separate frame than the original plot. I can plot the legend from plot commands. But not the legend from fill_between.

Here is a sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.linspace(0, 3.14*3, 100)
yy = np.sin (xx)
zz = yy +0.5

# I can draw a plot with legend
fig = plt.figure( )
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,)

line1, = ax.plot (xx, yy, label='xx')
line2, = ax.plot (xx, zz, label='yy')

fill0 = ax.fill_between (xx, yy, zz, label='filling', alpha=0.2, color='grey' ) 

ax.legend ( handles=[line1, line2, fill0])
plt.show()

# I can draw a empty plot with the legend of the lines 
plt.legend(handles=[line1, line2])
plt.show()

# I can't draw an empty plot with the legend of the fill
# Why ?
# Can I fix this ?

plt.legend(handles=[fill0,])
plt.show()
```

And now the error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Untitled.py", line 34, in <module>
 plt.legend(handles=[fill0,])
 File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2721, in legend 
return gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 417, in legend
self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 503, in __init__
self._init_legend_box(handles, labels, markerfirst)
File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py", line 767, in _init_legend_box
fontsize, handlebox))
File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 117, in legend_artist
fontsize, handlebox.get_transform())
File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib  /legend_handler.py", line 727, in create_artists
self.update_prop(p, orig_handle, legend)
File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 76, in update_prop
legend._set_artist_props(legend_handle)
File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py",    line 550, in _set_artist_props
a.set_figure(self.figure)
File "/Users/marti/anaconda3/envs/PROD/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 704, in set_figure
raise RuntimeError("Can not put single artist in "
RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure
```

Any hint to fix this?

Comment: Do you want 2 subplots? Like [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py) in the example after "or if you wanted to have 2 sub-plots"?

Comment: No,I need the legend on a separate plot, to put it separately in a PowerPoint.

Comment: You could put a fill between on the new axes and then set the view limits so it is not visible.

Comment: Yes, I can draw the legend on top of the fill_between. That's how I will do it. But I'm not very sastified of this :-((

Answer (score 0):

The `artist` object involved has deep nested data that matplotlib chooses not to allow its reuse on other axes. The workaround code can be something like this:

(only relevant code towards the end is given here)

```
# if want to plot the filled patch, must create anew
grey_patch1 = mpatches.Patch(label='filling1', alpha=0.2, color='grey')
plt.legend(handles=[line1, line2, grey_patch1])
plt.show()

#grey_patch1 can be reused, no need to recreate like this
grey_patch2 = mpatches.Patch(label='filling2', alpha=0.2, color='red')
plt.legend(handles=[grey_patch1, grey_patch2,])

plt.show()
```

The above code needs `import matplotlib.patches as mpatches`.

[image: mpatches]

Comment: OK, recreating a new, but simpler, object with the same color, alpha etc ... is a good workaround. Thanks for that idea, I will use it.

Anyway, I still feell that this is a workaround, and that it should not append.

Olivier

Comment: @Marti Actually it is a manual method that can be used to solve all requirements of complex legend making that you will find in real life. You have learnt that automatic approach has limitations. In your case, `fill0` (unlike `line1` and `line2` which are simple) is not allowed to reuse to avoid problem of graphic rendering in current version of matplotlib.